# Can a Wii U be "cleaned" of HBC traces?

Tags: wii-u, homebrew

If I install something like HBC on a Wii U, but later decide I don't want it anymore, is it possible to uninstall it completely or will it always be possible to check whether it had been installed?

Comment: What is HBC? A hacked firmware?

Comment: Home Brew Computer Club?

Comment: Home Brew Channel. it's a channel that allows custom apps to be run from an SD card, the channel is installed through an exploit.

Comment: Probably not, I always assume any modded console (whether hardware or software) should be considered defective from that point on and never connect to any online services with it, lest you want your account to be revoked. Because that is precisely what will happen on other consoles such as Xbox. If you reset the internal storage before connecting, then you will not have an issue though, but that's a tad bit inconvenient.

Comment: so if I have it on and connected to the internet while extra software is installed somewhere in memory, they'll delete my account?

Comment: @user16973 What Andon is saying is merely an assumption, there's nothing he's said that reinforces his statement, including assuming it's the same as how the Xbox works

Answer (score -1):

You can. I've installed the HBC on my Wii U with smash stack and then I deleted all the HBC files from my SD card and checked the stage builder and it was gone.

Comment: But are you 100% sure that there is no trace left?

Comment: I'm 100% sure. If it wasn't off, whenever I would go to the stage builder, it would've gone to the same terminal to go to the HBC installation.

Comment: You just deleted the homebrew files from the SD card. There could still be traces of it somewhere in the Wii U.

Comment: It might be somewhere in some kind of Wii U history hidden file or something but I'm pretty sure it wont affect any thing (software, internet services, etc.).

Comment: Well, if Nintendo has the means to check for it (which they likely do), then you could be in trouble. The least - you voided your warranty. The most - your console gets banned (which happened to the modded xbox 360)

Comment: You've offered no proof to go with your statement.  Unfortunately, taking you at your word doesn't work, as I don't believe you understand what you're talking about.